# Docker and Nginx proxy for production of an angular app

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am working on an app where I am calling a 3rd party API. My API in local and production looks something like the following

```
1. http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/search?jql=search_query
2. http://10.168.8.59:8090/rest/api/2/search?jql=search_query
```

Now in my `localhost` it works fine.
I create a `proxy.conf.json` to bypass the CORS error and it's the following:

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/rest/*": {
        "target": "https://subdomain.mydomin.com/",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I am trying to deploy the production in the server it is giving me the `404 Not Found error`.

I am using docker and here is my **DockerFile** looks like

```
FROM node:latest AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm i && npm run prod_build

FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm -rf ./*

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/. 
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I run the following 2 commands for building and running the docker container.

```
docker build -t p_admin --build-arg http_proxy=http://proxysubdom.proxydom.com:8080 --build-arg https_proxy=http://proxysubdom.proxydom.com:8080 .

docker run --env http_proxy=http://proxysubdom.proxydom.com:8080 --env https_proxy=http://proxysubdom.proxydom.com:8080 --rm -d -p 8090:80 p_admin
```

I looked for some solution but non that worked till now. Most of them said to configure `nginx.conf`. Here is the default `nginx.conf`.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

So far I edited the `nginx.conf` to the following

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name 10.168.8.59;

        location /rest {
            proxy_pass http://10.168.8.59:8090/rest;
        }
}
```

Still nothing and I do not know the above line that I have written are correct or not. First time working with Nginx and docker. All the given solution is making me more confused. What should I do here?